# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nextjs

Не могу понять в чем ошибка

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    imageMain: {type: String, required: true},
    imageHover: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    id: {type: Number, required: true},
    productUrl: {type: String, required: true},
    countInStock: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
},
{
  timestamps: true,
}
);

const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
export default Product;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[github](https://github.com/Dimasikkkk/slyatt-next)

Comment: mongoose.models = undefiend скорее всего. Выведите сам объект mongoose в консоль, чтобы посмотреть, какие поля в нём доступны

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать `optionalChaining`: `mongoose.models?.Product`. Но, по хорошему, стоит поискать причину того, почему models - пустой

Comment: А можно выкинуть мангус и пользоваться монгой с тс )